# What is missing to print *string_variable in C

Tags: arrays, c, string

I'm working on a project and need to replace letters in a string with dashes. I can't even get the string to print much less replace characters. I figured the issue is with my lack of understanding of pointers (which I have yet to cover).

I have tried iterating, copyining into another variable and %s but none are working... what am I missing?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
  printf("Welcome to the Computer Science Themed Hangman Game!\n The words the you will be asked to guess in this game will be related to computer science.\n");

  char words[15][20] = {"motherboard", "keyboard", "bytes", "programmer", "array", "processor", "loop", "algorithm", "intelligence", "boolean", "compute", "debug", "output", "function", "memory"};

  int i, mistakes = 0;

  int random_word_index = rand() % 15; //selects a random number from 0 to 15

  int word_length = strlen(words[random_word_index]); 
  printf("%d\n", word_length);

  char *selected_word = words[random_word_index];
  char word[20];
  strcpy(word, selected_word);
  printf("%s", word);

  char *current_status;
  printf("%s", current_status);
  
  for (i=0; i<word_length; ++i){
    current_status[i] = '_';
  }
  printf("%s", current_status);
```

Comment: Does word_length print?

Comment: Your `current_status` is an uninitialized pointer to a single `char`. Everything you do with that is undefined behaviour. Maybe you need `char current_status[20] = "";` ?

Comment: word length prints. I have tried printing other strings too and those work. The ```char current_status[20] = " ";``` didn't work